# Sublime Text 2: Opening single window and ignoring all other windows

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 2 on Linux. I use it as my primary programming editor. That is I have several tabs opened throughout the sessions. Yet sometimes I only want to quickly open a single file without opening all my other files from a previous session.

The default behaviour on my system is that the new opened file becomes a new tab besides my previously opened files. What I want, however, is to open just the new file (some sort of incognito browsing) without opening all the other previous files. That is, one tab in one window.

Does Sublime Text support that file opening behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the [User Settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) `hot_exit`and `remember_open_files` to `false`.

```js
{
  "hot_exit": false,
  "remember_open_files": false,
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nano. But this is not exactly what I want. I want to hide all previous windows in certain cases only such as when opening a single file quickly. The normal start behaviour should not change when for example launching Sublime Text via start menu. Is there no launch parameter to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Just set `open_files_in_new_window` to `false` in `preference -> setting, default`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `-n` parameter works as you want:

```
sublime_text.exe -n file.txt
```

But Windows behavior (not sure what about Linux) is that it creates two instances: one with previously edited files and another one only with the `file.txt`.

Anyway, my own experiences: I have almost always at least one instance of ST2 opened (I suppose something similar in your case) so in this case it is possible:

- `ctrl+shift+n` creates another ST2 instance and you can open the file in this (empty) one.
- If you have just opened the file (e.g. from command line without `-n`) and ST2 instance has been created not only with just opened file but also some other previously edited files in other tabs -- you can just simply *drag the file tab* and move it outside. Then new ST2 instance is created only with that file (i.e. one tab in one window).

Comment: I know about `-n`. This is probably the closest approach but still not completely what I want. When I quickly want to edit a file, I do not want to have the other window with all my other tabs opened, too. This is that in my case Sublime Text is not always opened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible but you can just drag the tab to somewhere in the middle of the screen and leave it. It will open in a new window. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For ***linux users*** of st3, adding `"open_files_in_new_window": false` does not add files/folder to existing st instance.

Workaround:

```sh
alias subl=‘subl -a’
```

*This solution works only when sublime is started through shell.*